Cannot find latest releases (core 2.25, map 3.25) jars uploaded in Maven central
I'd like to ask if there're any plans to upload the latest releases to Maven central. It seems that only ea versions are uploaded. I checked the README in Github and couldn't see any process or cadence to publish releases. Thanks.
I would like to download the latest releases from Maven central since even the ea releases are not always uploaded. For example, the chronicle-map-3.25ea7 is not in Maven central (latest one is ea6)

You can check the latest chronicle-bom to determine the latest version of any library. The latest chronicle-map is 3.26ea0 which is available on Maven Central. There are very little difference in chronicle-map since version 3.24. However, we have improved Java 21 support, and have stricter checks on java compiler lint and javadoc lint.

Only new EA (Early Access) versions are now uploaded to Maven Central. If you wish to download the non-EA (stable) versions, they are available with a software license and on Chronicle's Nexus server.

Welcome to Stack Overflow! Thank you for providing an answer. I've removed the last line, which pointed to an off-site email address, since all posts here should be self-contained, see [answer]. Additionally, if you're related with the product and answer here in a supportive capacity, do read Can I support my product on this site? on what behaviour is expected in that case.
